# Mapbox Android - How to draw GeoJSON polygon with holes

Tags: android, google-maps, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl

I need to draw a **GeoJSON poly with holes on a Mapbox Android SDK map**.

As the [GeoJSON spec](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#polygon) says,

> For type "Polygon", the "coordinates" member must be an array of LinearRing coordinate arrays. For Polygons with multiple rings, the first must be the exterior ring and any others must be interior rings or holes.

In Leaflet, Mapbox JS and Mapbox GL JS, loading GeoJSONs is handled by the library itself. As it can be seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erictheise/VaGy5/), the lib takes in account inner rings and thus draws holes correctly.

```
      [ //Outer ring
        [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]
      ],
      [ //Inner ring (hole)
        [100.35, 0.35], [100.65, 0.35], [100.65, 0.65], [100.35, 0.65], [100.35, 0.35]
      ]
```

When I look at the Android docs about drawing polys, there is no info whatsoever about holes. The example they give just loops over all the points and builds a PolyOptions with it : [Polygon drawing in Mapbox Android](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/polygon/).

I have been trying **building a polyOptions by adding all the points from the outer ring, then the inner rings**, one after the other. With the simple geoJSON from JSFiddle it works, it makes a hole. But with my more complex geoJSON the whole rendering is broken (the shape doesn't look like what it should).

After that, I tried **building one separate poly for every ring** of the geoJSON. Of course the shape is fine, but there are no holes, but stacked polys instead of them.

I have been looking for other options to [PolygonOptions](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/api/3.2.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/annotations/PolygonOptions.html) constructor but nothing else than points can be sent. I thought about drawing all the polys and then substracting shapes but I [found no such feature](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/api/3.2.0/).

[Here is my GeoJSON](http://geojson.io/#id=gist:anonymous/cf9d0d36121b1a255efe&map=15/42.6639/9.3008). It draws fine on mapbox JS. I am wondering if something is wrong with my GeoJSON, but I do not think so as it draws fine on geojson.io. Maybe I am missing something about geoJSON or mapbox. I did not find any documentation about that. I am considering switching to google maps, but that would mean restart the whole project from scratch.

Any idea ?

Comment: I may be wrong, but Mapbox defines `Polygon` as "a geometry annotation that's a closed loop of coordinates.", and according to the API reference there is no way to add holes to Polygons...

Comment: Polygon with interior holes is not yet implemented. There is this feature request for it https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/1729

Comment: That's what I thought.. thanks

Comment: Looks like this was implemented in April 2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a very long step by step process, I am now able to display holes in a polygon from a GeoJson data.

I am using this version of mapbox :

```
compile("com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.0.1@aar")
```

I use the layer system of Mapbox (FillLayer) combined with GeoJsonSource. Here are few lines of code to help:

```
//first create a feature
Feature polygon = Feature.fromJson("{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"name\":\"Home Zone\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[102.0, 2.0], [103.0, 2.0], [103.0, 3.0], [102.0, 3.0], [102.0, 2.0]],[[100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]],[[100.2, 0.2], [100.8, 0.2], [100.8, 0.8], [100.2, 0.8], [100.2, 0.2]]]}}");

//Then create a Feature Collection from it
FeatureCollection collection = FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(new Feature[]{polygon});

//Finally you  just need to use the collection to update your layer Source.
GeoJsonSource geoJsonSource = map.getSourceAs("yourSourceId");
geoJsonSource.setGeoJson(collection);
```

As a sample you can check the GeoJson here: 
http://geojson.io/

GeoJson Format : 
https://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id4

The GeoJson in plain text (Huge Square with hole in Malasya) : 
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"Home Zone"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[102.0, 2.0], [103.0, 2.0], [103.0, 3.0], [102.0, 3.0], [102.0, 2.0]],[[100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]],[[100.2, 0.2], [100.8, 0.2], [100.8, 0.8], [100.2, 0.8], [100.2, 0.2]]]}}